# Convert OpenPose skeleton structure to Kinect skeleton data structure?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, kinect

**Your help is needed**

I've a lot of saved data in **Kinect skeleton data structure** , the structure is as document here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/nuiskeleton.nui_skeleton_data.aspx

I'm trying to understand how to convert Kinect data to OpenPose skeleton data structure (Or vice versa) for the purpose of using the Kinect data as part of OpenPose development (supporting the academic research community).

**OpenPose structure** is documented here:
https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/blob/master/doc/output.md

I've already contacted the OpenPose development team to understand if they have such support, but they haven't replied yet.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd suggest writing an intermediary format which has the joints common to both KinectSDK and OpenPose and writing functions to convert to/from these two systems (bare in mind coordinate systems, not just joint IDs)